# How to get common lines for two variables with multiline text?

Tags: bash, nginx

I have line-by-line list of domains I got by

```
for domain in $(nginx -qT | grep -E "^[[:space:]]*server_name" | grep -Ev "^[[:space:]]*#" | sed 's/^[ \t]*//' | sed 's/server_name //g' | tr -d \; | grep -Ev "^_$" | sort | uniq); do echo $domain; done
```

from Nginx configuration.

---

Legibly:

```
for domain in $(
            nginx -qT |
            grep -E "^[[:space:]]*server_name" |
            grep -Ev "^[[:space:]]*#" |
            sed 's/^[ \t]*//' |
            sed 's/server_name //g' |
            tr -d \; |
            grep -Ev "^_$" |
            sort |
            uniq
        ); do
    echo $domain;
done
```

---

I also have several configuration files inside `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` directory that name is `domain.conf`.

I want to extract only domains from the first list that're described by configuration files from the second list.

What can I do to merge that two lists and extract from final list unique domains, keep only domains contained by both lists?

The second list I make by

```
for directory in $(grep -ir "include" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf | grep -Ev "^[[:space:]]*#" | grep -v "fastcgi_params\|mime.types" | sed 's/;//g' | grep -o "/.*"); do ls $directory; done
```

I want to use such things in Bash script, so that lists stay as values of variables not the files.
I've tried to use `comm` command also, but due the variables it doesn't work.

Comment: `comm` works, but needs the inputs sorted.

Comment: @choroba I left a note inside question that I use commands inside the script, so there I save output as variables neither separate files.
Due that I cannot use `comm` for it used only for files.

Comment: @choroba
How bad is it to save such output inside temp files, work with them and remove them at the end?

Comment: @aviro I'm sorry, I've confused everyone even myself.
I have directory marked `include`d in the main Nginx config file. I have the list of files for every domain insude `../conf.d/`. I also have list of domain I get by grepping `server_name` from Nginx configurationS. I want to get list of domain that are included according to the main config AND has its own configuration files.

Comment: @aviro I changed the title, hope it reflect my needs.

Comment: Providing a sample input and intended output is the best way to help people  understand what you want.

Comment: Don't cram all your code onto one line, especially when asking people to read it to help you with it. Please [edit] your question to fix your examples to use sensible newlines and indenting to make it clearer. I fixed one of them for you.

Comment: Please also [edit] your question to explain with examples what "I also have several configuration files inside `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` directory that name is `domain.conf`" means and how those files or directories relate to the file or directory `etc/nginx/nginx.conf` in your subsequent code `for directory in $(grep -ir "include" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf ...`.

Comment: unrelated to your question, but so is that whole loop: given how `sort` and `uniq` work by lines, what's the point of the loop in `for x in $(... |sort); do echo $x; done`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) feature in `bash`:

> Process substitution allows a process’s input or output to be referred
> to using a filename. It takes the form of
>
> `<(list)`
>
> or
>
> ```
> >(list)
> ```
>
> The process *list* is run asynchronously, and its input or output
> appears as a filename. This filename is passed as an argument to the
> current command as the result of the expansion.
> [...] If the `<(list)` form is used, the file passed as an argument should be read to obtain the output of list.

So, if you have two variables, you can sort their content and pass them as Process Substitution to the `comm` command:

```
comm -12 <(sort <<< "$VAR1" ) <(sort <<< "$VAR2")
```

For instance, assuming I want to find all numbers that are dividable both by 2 and 3 between 0 and 12:

```
$ VAR1=$(seq 0 2 12)
$ VAR2=$(seq 0 3 12)
$ comm -12 <(sort <<< "$VAR1" ) <(sort <<< "$VAR2")
0
12
6
```

Answer (score 0):

According @aviro answer the resulted query looks like:

```
    for directory in $(
        grep -ir "include" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf | 
        grep -Ev "^[[:space:]]*#" | 
        grep -v "fastcgi_params\|mime.types" | 
        sed 's/;//g' | 
        grep -o "/.*" | 
        sed 's/\.conf//g'
    );

        do
            ls $directory | 
            xargs -n 1 basename | 
            sed 's/\.conf//g'; 
        done
```

Comment: I don't see how it answers the question, nor how is it based on my answer...  There's nothing that's even slightly related to what I wrote in my answer.